# ¿Por qué no aparece el mapa integrado de google maps?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, google-maps

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es mostrar un mapa a manera de **popup** cuando se presiona un botón, pero cuando hago **click** en el botón, se muestra la ventana pero sin el mapa, como se muestra aquí en el código, estoy usando **bootstrap**:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <form action="#" method="get" class="advance-search-query input-night-rider yellow-theme">
  <div class="regular-search">                        
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Destino</label>
        <div class="input">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Busca el destino" class="pick-location form-controller" readonly="">
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seleecionarDestino">Seleccionar Destino</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="seleecionarDestino">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                  <!-- Modal Header -->
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Selecciona el Destino</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Modal body -->
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                      <div id="map">
                          <script>
                              function initMap() {
                                var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
                                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                                    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
                            }
                        </script>
                        <script async defer
                        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBqgmGIZhVwa44pOBhPM_FyjbD2l2CbMEU&callback=initMap">
                    </script>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya no hace falta me falto agregar los estilos

Comment: Edita la respuesta agregando lo que hiciste, así serás el héroe de más usuarios con la misma situación :D